# NoMethodError when creating new user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So when I submit all the info to create a new user: i get this error:

NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `sign_in' for #
[image]

I googled for it first and found answers where I was supposed to create a sessions_helper.rb file and include it in application.rb , did it all and when I refreshed after each step, it seemed to work. But now when I reloaded the page from the start again, I got the same error again.

Comment: Would like to calrify that, if the error pops after i submit my new user info,  I can refresh page and its gone, and the new user created. But why does the error pop up?

Comment: yeah, it is saved but the user is not signed in? Show us your session_helper file, your application controller and your users controller

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Veske/7536022

Comment: is `sign_in` method defined somewhere in your controllers (or somewhere visible from your controllers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veske showed me his code: https://gist.github.com/Veske/7536022

You have to define your method in the SessionHelper, it is not going to automatically be made for you :)

Comment: I thought it was a helper for some reason.. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: No problem, if you have any other questions feel free to ask. Also, since i see you're new here, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `sign_in` method in at least the `SessionsHelper` class.

If you'd like to use the [`devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for users creation/authentication, you'll have that method available in your code directly.

Comment: I belive it's better at first to learn from scratch: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails